# R shiny reactive graphing

Tags: r, shiny

I am currently working on a html output of R that uses the package "shiny". I am trying to make a reactive user interactive box and whisker plot that the user can manipulate the variables being used.

**Server**

```
library(shiny)
require(mosaic)
cdc <- read.csv("~/Econ 263 Shared/cdc.csv")
cdc = cdc
cdc <- transform(cdc, bmi = (cdc$weight / cdc$height^2) * 703)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    switch(input$cdc,
       "gender" = cdc$gender,
       "height" = cdc$height,
       "weight" = cdc$weight)

varr <- datasetInput()
bwplot(bmi ~ gender, data = cdc)
  })

})
```

**UI**

```
library(shiny)
require(mosaic)
cdc <- read.csv("~/Econ 263 Shared/cdc.csv")
cdc = cdc
cdc <- transform(cdc, bmi = (cdc$weight / cdc$height^2) * 703)


shinyUI(fluidPage(


titlePanel("BWplot!"),


sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  selectInput("dataset", "Choose a dataset:", 
              choices = c("gender", "height", "weight"))
),

mainPanel(
  plotOutput("distPlot")
     )
  )
))
```

This is the error that I receive when I run the current code:

Error in switch(input$cdc, gender = cdc$gender, height = cdc$height, weight = cdc$weight) : 
  EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: input$cdc does not exist. Instead of switch(input$cdc, ... ) try switch(ìnput$dataset, ...)